# JQuery character counter with line breaks in a contenteditable DIV

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("input", "#textbox", function(event){
    var characters = $(this).text().length;
    $(".character-counter").html(160 - characters);
});
```

And the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="character-counter">160</div>
```

I want the character counter to count the new line breaks as `1` character. For example:

```
Line 1
Line 2

Line 4
```

The counter shows `142`, and I want it to show `139` (counting the line breaks).

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth I need to count the line breaks as characters.

Comment: you mean characters in `#textbox` ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth Yes, the text is written in `#textbox` and the total of characters is shown in `.character-counter`, but the line breaks do not count.

Comment: what is this : `on("input"` ??

Comment: @SupunPraneeth The event that is executed when the user types in `#textbox`. Each time the user writes something the counter would show the total of characters.

Comment: there are no such even call `input` and your `"#textbox"` is not a input box

Comment: @SupunPraneeth It works to be a contenteditable `div`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count line separately

```
$(document).on("input", "#textbox", function(event){
    var characters = $(this).text().length;
    if (characters) characters += $(this).find(">").length;

   $(".character-counter").html(160 - characters);
});
```

https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/PaavNo

in `contenteditable` new line mean new element, that's why it doesn't count lines.

Comment: Why when I add a new line without having written anything does it count as `2` characters?

Comment: because it counts line whether its has characters or not

Comment: ahh i see you mean it count two lines right ? I'll check

Comment: Exactly, if you insert a line break at the beginning it counts as 2 characters, when it should be only 1.

Comment: it because when you press enter  without typing anything it creates 2 lines.  I think best things to do is don't count if there are no any characters

Comment: I've fixed the code, but I think it's not very professional (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKKoZw)

Comment: i tried  something like yours but first when you type enter and then type some character then again press enter so that's count is 3 right ? but it says 4